# let seaborn pointplot show NaN data with a line

Tags: python, visualization, seaborn, errorbar

I'm trying to plot a dataframe looks like this:

```
Quarter, score
1890.1, NaN
1890.2, 0.000000
1890.2, 0.000000
1890.2, -0.073413
1890.2, 0.000000
1890.3, NaN
1890.4, NaN
1891.1, NaN
1891.2, NaN
1891.3, NaN
1891.4, NaN
1892.1, NaN
1892.2, 0.000000
1892.3, 0.000000
```

In order to do error bar plot, I used seaborn pointplot. My problem is, the NaN values are not shown. So I get a plot with gaps like this: [image: graph with missing NaN values]
Is there any way to let seaborn show the missing data with a line? Thanks a lot for your help!

My code are as follows:

```
a4_dims = (15, 8.27)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=a4_dims)
ax = sns.pointplot(x="Quarter", y="score", data=df, aspect=2.5, capsize=.5)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: Could use add a drawing how the line should look?

Comment: As you can see in the figure, some points are connected with lines. Same simple straight line is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try setting join

'If True, lines will be drawn between point estimates at the same hue level.'

Alternatively, you could use:

[use pandas.DataFrame.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

`df['score']=df['score'].fillna(method='ffill')`

depending on how you would like the line to be filled you can use

> ffill: propagate last valid observation forward to next valid 
>    bfill: use NEXT valid observation to fill gap

Comment: I assume this works similar as df.interpolate()? The problem with filling values is that in plot I will get not only the lines but also datapoints that originally doesn't exit in the dataframe :(